# Struts2 to ajax json response how to set image on Jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts2

```
Struts2 to ajax json response can we set it on jsp first and display jsp as response inside
```

the ajax success
here is the code it becomes very painful to write jsp/html tag using dynamic value in jquery so is there any way that after response we can display the html in jsp and that jsp is returned or display inside function(response){  }.

```
        $.post("add_cmt?content1="+comment_text+"&postupload_id1="+getpID, {
        }, function(response){
            $('#CommentPosted'+getpID).prepend("<div>"+'<img src="images/'+comment_userid+"/"+comment_album+"/"+comment_pic +'" width="50" height="50" />'+"<b>"+comment_name+"</b>"+"   "+comment_text+"<br/>"+"few Seconds ago"+"</div>");

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes we can send jsp/html page in ajax response

create a jsp page which you want to get as response then on `$post` success display response in any div

```
 $.post("add_cmt?content1="+comment_text+"&postupload_id1="+getpID, {
        }, function(response){
            $('#CommentPosted'+getpID).prepend(response);

        });
```

Ajax jsp

Your Content

See this for better explanation
    http://ebhor.com/html-jsp-page-response-in-ajax-get-method/